# How to get all nodes from a DOM Document (Elements, Attributes etc)

Tags: java, dom

I am trying to get all nodes that are part of a document and am only able to get the element nodes, using `getElementByTagName("*")`. But this does not return the other nodes viz. attribute and other nodes.

Is there an api available or do I have to iterate further on these elements to get there attribute nodes?

This is what I am trying now; Need to know if there is any other way or a direct api for the same

```
private static List<Node> getAllNodes(Document doc) {
        List<Node> returnList = new LinkedList<>();
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");

        for (int index = 0; index < nodes.getLength(); index++) {
            returnList.add(nodes.item(index));

            NamedNodeMap attribList = nodes.item(index).getAttributes();
            if (attribList == null) {
                continue;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < attribList.getLength(); j++) {
                returnList.add(attribList.item(j));
            }
        }
        return returnList;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please paste your dom node file.

Comment: Do note that the semantic of attributes changes with [DOM4](attributes are not nodes anymore), they no longer implement the Nodes interface. This may not be relevant for java, but the semantic distinction between nodes of the DOM tree and attributes attached to nodes is still something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

This is worked for me.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
            //your file object put here.
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
            for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nList.item(i);

                Element element = (Element) node;
                System.out.println(element.getNodeName())
            }
```

**EDIT :**

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
                //your file object put here.
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
                for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node node = nList.item(i);

                    Element element = (Element) node;
                    System.out.println(element.getNodeName());
                    String name = element.getAttribute("name");
                    System.out.println(name);
                }
```

Comment: This returns all the Nodes that are type of Element, I want all the attributes of those element's attributes too .

Comment: please paste your document here.

Comment: The requirement is for any xml. in case of `<person sex="female">
  <firstname>Anna</firstname>
</person>`
I should be able to get "person" node "sex" node and "firstname" node

Comment: please see the edits. you can get the attribute by name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`getChildNodes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getChildNodes()) that give you all the nodes (attributes, elements ecc...)

```
Document doc; //Your Document class
printChild(doc);

public void printChild(Node node)
{
    NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
    System.out.println("Node: " + node.getNodeType() + ", " + node.getLocalName());
    for(int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++)
    {
        Node childNode = childNodes.item(i);
        if(childNode.hasAttributes())
        {
            System.out.println("Attributes: " + childNode.getAttributes()); //just an example...
            //Here you can iterate over each attributes to do something
        }

        if(childNode.hasChildNodes())
        {
            System.out.println(""); //just an empty string
            printChild(childNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provides all the nodes but only of the current node. In case of the document node I get only the immediate children of the document node, I need all the nodes in that document.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using selenium ( just guessing ), you should use findElements(By.xpath("*")), the tag name is not treated as regex, that's  why the '*' is not working.

Comment: I am trying this in java, not using selenium